# Doing things when a button is down

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'd like to have it so that a function is called only when I click somewhere after I have clicked another button(lets say that this button is 'down' when I click elsewhere).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If you're set on using buttons, you could keep track of the button's state in a variable, but HTML buttons do not have a "down" state. Checkboxes are what you want -- they have a native `checked` atribute you can read to see if it is `yes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first button's `click` event handler, set a flag to `true`. In the 2nd button's `click` event handler check to see if the flag is `true`, then do your logic.

```
var button1Clicked = false; // what you call "down"
$('#button1').click(function() { button1Clicked = true });
$('#button2').click(function() { if (button1Clicked) { /* magic */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

To check whether an other click has occured before, just store that in a variable:

```
var firstButtonClicked = false;
firstButton.on("click", function() { firstButtonClicked = true; });
secondButton.on("click", function() {
    if (firstButtonClicked) {
        // do something
    } else {
        alert("You need to click the other button first");
    }
});
```

In every case you should give the user some feedback that he needs to click the one button first. The best solution would be to set the second one to `disabled`, and activate it from the first button that has a descriptive label.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the second button's click handler when the first button is clicked for the first time. This way, the function doesn't exist until after the first button has been clicked:

```
$('#button1').one('click', function() {
    // Do stuff for first button's click

    // Create second click handler to be called when second button clicked
    $('#button2').click(function() {
        // Do stuff for second button's click
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to determine the state of the button, like

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('long');
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', function(){
    $('.long').removeClass('long');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/YdqJX/)